# What is the significance of the --example flag on creating NextJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am beginning to learn NextJs and I came across this command to create a new NextJs App

```
npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"
```

I wish to know the significance of the --example flag. I could not find any explanation for that.

Comment: Don't use NexJS, but it looks like it's saying   "use the next parameter as a URL to fetch some example code from"..  I assume this will then merge this with some base nextJS code.

Answer (score 1):

The `--example` flag tells `create-next-app` which template to use. Here's the flag in [the source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/ef69aca4df648949aa0011b1431fafd6f21dafe5/packages/create-next-app/index.ts#L43-L51):

```js
  .option(
    '-e, --example [name]|[github-url]',
    `
  An example to bootstrap the app with. You can use an example name
  from the official Next.js repo or a GitHub URL. The URL can use
  any branch and/or subdirectory
`
  )
```

There's also a note about it in [the tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup):

> Under the hood, this uses the tool called `create-next-app`, which bootstraps a Next.js app for you. It uses [this template](https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter) through the `--example` flag.